# How to execute a trained model with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, pre-trained-model

I downloaded a template and the same is in this path: \home\wisehipoppotamus\LLAMA

Inside the LLAMA folder there are 4 folders referring to each model, which are the folders:

- 7B
- 13B
- 30B
- 65B

Plus 2 files:

- tokenizer.model
- tokenizer_checklist.chk

Here is a print of the directory:

[LLAMA Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVXPr.png)

My python code to run the model looks like this:

```
import torch
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('/home/wisehipoppotamus/LLAMA')
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('/home/wisehipoppotamus/LLAMA/65B')


input_text = "What are penguins?"
encoded_input = tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors='en')
output = model.generate(encoded_input, max_length=200, num_return_sequences=1)
decoded_output = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
print(decoded_output)
```

When I run this code I get these err

```
python3 ai_model_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wisehipoppotamus/ai_model_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('/home/wisehipoppotamus/LLAMA')
  File "/home/wisehipoppotamus/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 1788, in from_pretrained
    raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: Can't load tokenizer for '/home/wisehipoppotamus/LLAMA'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure '/home/wisehipoppotamus/LLAMA' is the correct path to a directory containing all relevant files for a GPT2Tokenizer tokenizer.
```

From what I saw the paths are correct for the tokenizer and for the specific model, respectively. I am not understanding this error.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks.